# Custom serialization of Collection<T> using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd like to convert a java collection like this

```
public Collection<SomeDTO> getPages()
{
    return pages;
}
```

to a json array like this:

```
pages: [{DTO}, {DTO}, {DTO}]
```

This works out of the box, but I'd now like to not use the default serialization for the `SomeDTO`. Specifically, I'd like to write out an object that includes a combination of the values and some additional calculations based on the `SomeDTO`.

I tried using the `@JsonSerialize(using=Serializer)` but when this is applied onto the Collection Method, it excpects me to serialize the collection myself. It's doable, but I woudl prefer to simply define how JUST the DTOs are serialized.

Ideas?

Comment: I think @JsonSerialize(using=Serializer) can be used on a class level, too. But somehow this is not working for me. Can anyone show me a working example of how to apply this to a class?

Comment: Could you detail "values and some additional calculations based on the SomeDTO" ? How does your output should look like ? Will your output look like this -> pages: [{DTO}, {DTO}, {DTO}, {Calculated-DTO}] ? or like this -> pages: [{Calculated-DTO}, {Calculated-DTO}, {Calculated-DTO}] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not help immediately, but the problem with @JsonSerialize is that unlike @JsonDeserialize which has both "using" (for type itself, like ArrayList) and "contentUsing" (for value type); @JsonSerialize does not have latter until Jackson 1.8 (it does exist in trunk).

But you can register custom serializer for type SomeDTO if you want, and that will be used when serializing collections that have them as value types.
There are multiple ways to register such custom serializers; one is to just add @JsonSerializer(using=...) to declaration of SomeDTO. And if you can not add it to class definition (third-party class), you can use mix-in annotations to associate annotations.

Comment: thanx, adding @JsonSerializer to the dto that should be transformed worked. In the serializer, I created a new value dto that was then written to the json output via generator.writeObject(o) - that worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding getters to SomeDto for the additional fields you want to serialize?

Comment: That is indeed a solution I also came up with and considered. The approach would be to mark the unwanted properties as  @JsonIgnore or @XmlTransient and add properties specifically for the desired output that is based on the other properties. Thanx!